# Cache Angular2 bundle in Redis? Good or not?

Tags: angular, webpack, redis

Is it a good practice to cache Angular2 generated bundle.js in REDIS?

My idea is on starting the NodeJS server, to load the angular2 bundle in Redis and then on initializing the page, just to get it from the redis cache rather than waiting for downloading it, since is pretty big already, around 3-4-5MB.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed help, it will be downloaded any way, because it's cached on server side and will be consumed on client side. Any way, Node app shouldn't be encumbered with FS/HTTP caching. This is supposed to be done in another layer that is dedicated for this job - Nginx, Varnish, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad.

Redis is an in-memory data-store & is useful for cache-ing data, not static assets.

For static assets, Please use a server like nginx/varnish as suggested by estus. It is also not a good practice to serve static assets through nodeJS as nginx would be faster and can do a much better job at serving, cache-ing and handling re-directs.

Comment: Ok, so you say that is not better to host angular2 app on nodejs environmen? How to host the app then? In something like aws S3? or just to run the angular on some EC2 instance on its own? without the node serving it?

Comment: If AWS is the infra you are using, then you can host your angular app on s3 and push it to cloudfront to distribute it. You can follow this article to set up s3 for hosting : https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af

Comment: If you donot want to use s3, you can use the ec2 on which you have installed your node server to host your app but install nginx on it to reverse proxy to your node server if it is a server request or serve the index.html of your angular 2 project if it is a root request